# netutils_t cannot open initrc_tmp_t files

Tags: selinux

I'm running SELinux (in permissive mode) on RHEL 6.5 and seeing a strange `denied` error in my audit.log. Supposedly, the [netutils_t](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netutils_selinux) process type can manage files labeled with the initrc_tmp_t type, but that does not seem to be the case for me. Details are below.

I have an init script that will run `tcpdump` and write the gzipped pcap files to a secondary drive (mounted to /mydrive). The full path of the stored pcap log files is /mydrive/Logs/Netlog_*date*.pcap.gz.

I used `semanage` and `restorecon` so that any new files in /mydrive/Logs/ are labeled with initrc_tmp_t:

```
semanage fcontext --add --type initrc_tmp_t "/mydrive/Logs(/.*)?"
restorecon -r -v /mydrive/Logs
```

`ls -Z` shows that on subsequent boots, new pcap.gz files in /mydrive/Logs created by my script are marked with initrc_tmp_t, as expected.

However, the audit.log file shows `denied` complaints:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1469228718.525:138): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1535 comm="tcpdump" name="Netlog_07-22-2016_23-05-18.pcap.gz" dev=sdb1 ino=12845323 scontext=system_u:system_r:netutils_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:initrc_tmp_t:s0 tclass=file
```

`audit2why` shows:

```
Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.
```

`audit2allow` shows:

```
#============= netutils_t =============
allow netutils_t initrc_tmp_t:file open;
```

Any idea why this might be? According to the man page, netutils_t should already be able to open initrc_tmp_t